# Package.json proxy alternative to React SSR production app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side

So I would like to find a way how to implement this part of package.json to my server.js which is responsible for my React App server side rendering.

```
"proxy": {
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3501"
    },
    "/media/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3501"
    }
  },
```

I have looked into some of the libraries like `express-http-proxy` and `http-proxy-middleware` but I cannot find a working solution.

Last I tried:

```
import proxy from 'express-http-proxy';
...

app.use('/api', proxy('http://localhost:3501/api/*'));

app.use('/media', proxy('http://localhost:3501/media/*'));
```

It logs 404 and the path is basically right, just without "/api/" should be "/api/posts/" but logs only "/posts/".

Comment: Why do you need the proxy? Maybe there is a workaround so that you don't have to use one. Is it a MERN stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware)

It is just as simple as that. Replace your current code with this:

```
import proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';

...

app.use('/media/*', proxy({target: 'http://localhost:3500', changeOrigin: true}));
```